# Google.apis returns error code 400 after creating maximum amount of service account keys

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-cloud-iam, google-people-api

We are using Google.apis Version 1.36.1 SDK in order to create service account keys for GCP Service accounts.

When we reach maximum amount of keys (10) instead of getting a valid error message / error code we recieve a general 400 error code with a "Precondition check failed." message.

We used to get error code 429 indicating we have reached maximum amount of keys.

Current GoogleApiException object :

```
Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Precondition check failed. [400]
Errors [
    Message[Precondition check failed.] Location[ - ] Reason[failedPrecondition] Domain[global]
]
```

The current return code does not provide us with enough information, Is there any other way for us to know the reason of the failure ?

Answer (score 0):

This error message is also related to limits. You can take the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Request.Errors) for the Classroom API as an example.

I have found myself in a similar situation where we were deleting service account keys to immediately create new ones. We were getting the same error because there is a delay on the system where it can take from 60-90 seconds to delete the key for you to be able to create it again.

Comment: thanks a lot! I found the article really helpful. 
This is not the same exact API from google, Too bad we cannot exactly determine what is the reason for getting this error code but looks like this is the only official place where Google actually added 400 'Precondition check failed' error to their documentation